# Cross-thread operation not valid error

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

Can anyone please tell me how to fix this? I keep getting a "Cross-thread operation not valid error." I feel like I need to somehow add a public event within the separate thread, but don't know how. Thanks

```
Public Class Form2
    Public WithEvents _tasks As New Tasks

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        _tasks.StartThread()
    End Sub

    Public Sub task1(msg As String) Handles _tasks.DoTask1
        TextBox1.Text &= msg
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class Tasks
    Public Event DoTask1(msg As String)

    Public _thread As New Thread(AddressOf TasksThread)

    Public Sub StartThread()
        _thread.Start()
    End Sub

    Public Sub TasksThread()
        Do
            RaiseEvent DoTask1("1")
            Thread.sleep(1000)
        Loop While True
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cross-thread operation not valid: Control accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/142003/cross-thread-operation-not-valid-control-accessed-from-a-thread-other-than-the)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Public Sub task1(msg As String) Handles _tasks.DoTask1

    If TextBox1.InvokeRequired Then
        TextBox1.Invoke(Sub() TextBox1.Text &= msg)
    Else
        TextBox1.Text &= msg
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Just to confirm, when trying to access a control on a form from another thread, I must use Invoke or BeginInvoke. If I am trying to access a class from another thread, I can either pass the class by reference or use RaiseEvent, I just have to make sure that I synclock variables that are being written to within that class. Does this sounds like a good standard? Do you know a good book I can read about multithreading? Everything is so hard to understand. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You're modifying a UI control from a thread other than the UI thread. You need to marshal your event handler call to `Textbox1.Text`.

There are dozens of similar SO questions and answers related to this. Here's [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142003/cross-thread-operation-not-valid-control-accessed-from-a-thread-other-than-the?rq=1).

Comment: So I guess RaiseEvent is not meant for cross threads, I have to use Invoke?

Comment: RaiseEvent will trigger an event that typically will fire on its own thread. Your handler `Public Sub task1(msg As String) Handles _tasks.DoTask1` will therefor be executing from a non-UI thread. Since it tries to touch a UI object, that's where you'll get the exception and that's where you'll need to use Invoke or some other method to marshal the call back to the UI thread.